# How to serialize objects so their nested entities are represented by a id?

Tags: php, symfony, design-patterns, serialization, doctrine-orm

Let's say there are objects ***A***, ***B*** and ***C***. They're all Doctrine ORM entities.

Object ***A*** is the aggregate root - it's a composite of ***B*** and ***C*** objects.
Serializing object ***A*** returns it's own data and also properties of ***B*** and ***C***. This is something I want to change in the most graceful way possible.

Object ***A*** should serialize in a way that retains it's properties but represents ***B*** and ***C*** with one of their properties - in this case their id. JSON example:

```js
{
  "objA": {
    "property": true,
    "objB": 10,
    "objC": "a1c81b5a-6ecd-4c40-a541-f779b907418c",
  }
}
```

I was wondering what is a good way that could be used system-wide to achieve that.

This is how I want to represent nested entities in almost every situation in my application - someone suggested me to implement Presentation Models or ViewModels for every case, but isn't there a way to configure this in Doctrine or Symfony's serializer?

Comment: 171, 172, 173 and 174 would help you [here](http://www.inanzzz.com/index.php/posts/symfony). You would create one model class `ObjectA` and have all its properties listed in it along with `objectBid` and `objectCid`. When it comes to mapping all those data, "bcc" library will help you. You just need to study those examples a bit. Technically you will map entity object to a model object.

Comment: Thanks @BentCoder , I haven't thought about using a mapper but it seems like a good fit

Comment: It will save you a lot of development time. On top of that, you get rid of manual mapping too as long as the property names in entity and model classes are same. BCC automatically recognises and maps the properties itself. Don't worry if they do differ, it still maps them with very little interaction. Have a look at the [documentation](https://github.com/michelsalib/BCCAutoMapperBundle). It is just soo simple!

Comment: Have you looked at symfony's serializer component docs? Seems to be exactly what you need. http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/serializer.html